# Servlet on servicemix v5.3.2

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

Faced with a problem during migration from SM v5.1.4 to v5.3.2.
The code below works perfectly on v5.1.4. The servlet is registred with a key "*CamelServlet*" in the HttpRegistry and it has a single provider which is CamelHttpTransportServlet and a single consumer *Consumer[servlet:///?matchOnUriPrefix=true]*.

On the version 5.3.2 for some reason there are two HttpRegistries are registred. The first one again with a key "*CamelServlet*" and this registry has a consumer *Consumer[servlet:///?matchOnUriPrefix=true]* which is fine, but the provider is registered for a different instance of HttpRegistry  with a key *org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServletModel-XXX* (where XXX is a generated integer).  So now I have two HttpRegistries, one has providers, another one consumers. With this the "*mainRoute*" is never called because consumers are registered not for the *CamelServlet* but for some another HttpRegistry. So when a request comes, the code in the service method of the CamelServlet.class which is marked with *{1}* will return null for a consumer and no route will be called.

Does anyone has an idea what is wrong and how I can fix that? Thank you

**CamelServlet**

```
package org.apache.camel.component.http;

public class CamelServlet extends HttpServlet {
.........................

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.trace("Service: {}", request);

        // Is there a consumer registered for the request.
        HttpConsumer consumer = resolve(request); //{1} resolve a consumer
        if (consumer == null) {
            log.debug("No consumer to service request {}", request);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }    
    }

....................

}
```

**Camel context**

```
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd

                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
                       http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd"
    >

<!--camel servlet-->
<bean id="camelServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet"/>

<osgi:service ref="camelServlet">
    <osgi:interfaces>
        <value>javax.servlet.Servlet</value>
        <value>org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
    <osgi:service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/test" />
        <entry key="matchOnUriPrefix" value="true" />
        <entry key="servlet-name" value="CamelServlet"/>
    </osgi:service-properties>
</osgi:service>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" streamCache="true" trace="false">

    <route id="mainRoute">
        <from uri="servlet:///?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
        <log message="Process mainRoute"/>
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. With the servicemix v5.3.2 a PAX wrapper is used and the problem was inside `org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.tracker.ServletTracker` in the `createWebElement` method.

With the Servicemix v5.1.4 all service-properties other than standard ones were added as initial parameters for a servlet. SM v 3.5.2 by default simply ignores all service-properties which name does not start with "init." prefix (defined in `org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.ExtenderConstants.DEFAULT_INIT_PREFIX_PROP`). So that leaded to the fact that servlet-name property was ignored and in this case an id of an `ServletModel` object was used which happens to be in the *org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ServletModel-XXX* format. Simple solution for me was to add an '*init.*' prefix to the property so the spring conext looked like the following

```
...........
<osgi:service ref="camelServlet">
    <osgi:interfaces>
        <value>javax.servlet.Servlet</value>
        <value>org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
    <osgi:service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/test" />
        <entry key="matchOnUriPrefix" value="true" />
        <entry key="init.servlet-name" value="CamelServlet"/>
    </osgi:service-properties>
</osgi:service>
...........
```

Did not find a description of this new feature in the documentation, so possibly there is a way to override this behavior in a config, but I have not looked for that.
Hope that may save time for somebody who ran into the same issue.